# How to render json some variables without brackets inside brackets on AMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I'd like to know if is possible to render variable without params on render with brackets with AMS?

for exemple:

`render json: { comments: @comments, status: 200, hasMore: hasMore }`

i'd like to render just @comments without the comments: and with hasMore: hasMore showing on the json that is just possible inside brackets!

with this way

```
render json: @comments, hasMore: hasMore,  include: ['user', 'replies.**']
```

did not show the hasMore on the json

Comment: that won't work.  You need to build a json type object to render it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're rendering json, you need to make sure what you pass as json is actually valid json.  Here's a most simple example:

```
# this does not work and will throw a syntax error
render json: 'foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'
```

but

```
# this works
render json: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}


# this works because it will render an array type
render json: @comments # assuming that is a collection
```